# How is join+into clause converted to GroupJoin

Tags: c#, linq, join

How can I write the code:

```
var list = from uint x in M join uint y in N on x equals y into templist
           from uint z in templist join uint t in R on z equals t select z;
```

in terms of `Join` or `GroupJoin` methods?

According to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause?view=netframework-4.8) the combination of `join` and `into` is converted to a call to `GroupJoin`. I just want to know how is `GroupJoin` called with the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my hand translation, preserving your range variables and type information:

```
var list = M.GroupJoin(N, (uint x) => x, (uint y) => y, (uint x, IEnumerable<uint> templist) => templist)
            .SelectMany(templist => templist.Join(R, z => z, t => t, (z, t) => z));
```

Using [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), you can put in a query on an `IQueryable` and get back a lambda translation.

Put this in LINQPad:

```
var M = Enumerable.Empty<uint>().AsQueryable();
var N = Enumerable.Empty<uint>().AsQueryable();
var R = Enumerable.Empty<uint>().AsQueryable();

var list = from uint x in M
           join uint y in N on x equals y into templist
           from uint z in templist
           join uint t in R on z equals t
           select z;

list.Dump();
```

and on the lambda tab get this back:

```
System.Linq.EmptyPartition`1[System.UInt32]
   .Cast ()
   .GroupJoin (
      System.Linq.EmptyPartition`1[System.UInt32]
         .Cast (), 
      x => x, 
      y => y, 
      (x, templist) => 
         new  
         {
            x = x, 
            templist = templist
         }
   )
   .SelectMany (
      temp0 => temp0.templist.Cast (), 
      (temp0, z) => 
         new  
         {
            temp0 = temp0, 
            z = z
         }
   )
   .Join (
      System.Linq.EmptyPartition`1[System.UInt32]
         .Cast (), 
      temp1 => temp1.z, 
      t => t, 
      (temp1, t) => temp1.z
   )
```

So it seems like the compiler prefers to translate to the `SelectMany` and chain the `Join` rather than nest the `Join`. It also seems like the compiler likes to pass all the range variables along, rather than noticing e.g. that `x` and `temp0` is no longer needed and just `z` could be passed into the `Join`.

I would have written my original like so using my preferred range variable naming:

```
var list = M.GroupJoin(N, m => m, n => n, (m, nj) => nj)
            .SelectMany(nj => nj.Join(R, n => n, r => r, (n, r) => n));
```

I would emulate the compiler fluent chaining like so:

```
var list = M.GroupJoin(N, m => n, n => n, (m, nj) => nj)
            .SelectMany(nj => nj)
            .Join(R, n => n, r => r, (n, r) => n);
```

Finally, given the result, there is no reason to use a `GroupJoin` so I would just have done:

```
var list = from x in M
           join y in N on x equals y
           join t in R on y equals t
           select y;
```

Or in lambda syntax:

```
var list = M.Join(N, m => m, n => n, (m, n) => n)
            .Join(R, n => n, r => r, (n, r) => n);
```